# Java using supertype of several enums

Tags: java, enums, supertype

I want to be able to use a supertype over different enums, the code consists of three parts:

Manager.search:

```
public final List<B> search(final Order order, final Field field, final AbstractConstraint... c) throws SearchException {
    if (c.length == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("orm.Manager.search: c.length == 0");
    }
    try {
        List<B> beans = new ArrayList<>();

        for (AbstractConstraint constraint : c) {
            try (PreparedStatement ps = new QueryBuilder(connection, tableName(), getPaths(), searchQuery()).add(constraint).order(order, field).build();ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    beans.add(createBean(rs));
                }
            }
        }
        return beans;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Manager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        throw new SearchException(ex);
    }
}
```

The `order` and `field` variables are most important here.

The auto-generated TemplateAttributeField.java:

```
public enum TemplateAttributeField implements Field {
    templateId,
    attributeOrder,
    attributeName,
    x1,
    x2;
}
```

And the calling code:

```
try (TemplateAttributeManager templateAttributeManager = ManagerFactory.getTemplateAttributeManager()) {
    List<TemplateAttributeBean> templateAttributes = null;
    try {
        templateAttributes = templateAttributeManager.search(Order.ASCENDING, TemplateAttributeField.attributeOrder, new TemplateAttributeConstraint.Builder().templateId(template.getTemplateId()).build());
    } catch (SearchException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(OutputProcessor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    for (Word word : words) {

    }
}
```

However at `templateAttributes = ...` I get the following exception/error:

```
no suitable method found for search(Order,TemplateAttributeField,TemplateAttributeConstraint)
    method Manager.search(Order,Field,AbstractConstraint...) is not applicable
      (actual argument TemplateAttributeField cannot be converted to Field by method invocation conversion)
```

And the `Field` class is on more than an interface which does not prevent extra functionality.

Am I missing something here, or how should I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that both `Field`s are the same? If code gets generated, are you sure there is no second `Field` interface generated as well?

Comment: It was a stupid mistake, had actually not even to do with the auto generation.  I have an `orm.Field` and `orm.fields.Field` and subsequently in the `orm.Manager` class I wanted to use the `orm.fields.Field` and hence it automatically choose the package-specific one.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to create a minimal working example, but it seems to work for me. Could you try if this works for you and is the same as you require?

```
public class Test {
    static interface I {}
    static enum E implements I {A}
    static void m(I i) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        m(E.A);
    }
}
```

Also ensure that you implement the same `Field` interface in your `enum` as you require in your method. Maybe there's a name clash and you're using interfaces from different packages.

Comment: Should work as expected, I had a nasty bug as commented on the OP.

Comment: Okay great, just thought of that problem as well :)